# variable in reading data structure in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I would like to read a particular variable `AandB_cossy` from N Matlab files. To do this I have used as below. To read the values, we generally use `Noplate1.AandB_cossy(:,1)`. This works fine. My doubt is once I assign to `Noplate1`, `Noplate2`, `Noplate3`, how do I read without specifying the `AandB_cossy` again to read the values for each one? Is it possible to do something like `Noplate1.var(:,1)`?? Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

```
clearvars; close all; clc;
var='AandB_cossy';
Noplate1=load('dummy1.mat',var);
Noplate2=load('dumsabs2.mat',var);
Noplate3=load('yipposbn123.mat',var);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `var` to index into the struct `Noplate1` as follows:

```
var = 'AandB_cossy';
Noplate1 = load('dummy1.mat',var);
Noplate1.(var)(:,1);
```

---

To read many files, the easiest is to list their names in a list (you can use the function `dir` to generate this list if it is all files in a directory, for example). Then you iterate over the list and read the values into a cell array:

```
fnames = {'dummy1.mat','dumsabs2.mat','yipposbn123.mat'};
var = 'AandB_cossy';
Noplate = cell(size(fnames));
for ii = 1:numel(fnames)
   tmp = load(fnames{ii},var);
   Noplate{ii} = tmp.(var);
end
```

Now you can access each data array as `Noplate{1}`, `Noplate{2}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have another doubt. I would like to use the same in for loop. In this regard, I wish to convert the char to struct. However matlab throws an error as it is not possible. could you please tell how to do the same? Noplate1 keeps changing in the loop to Noplate2, Noplate3.... etc. I have used something like this in for loop. struct(strcat('Noplate',num2str(i))).(var)(:,1); But the error is "Error: Functions cannot be indexed using {}
or . indexing."

Comment: for i=1:N x=strcat('Noplate',num2str(i)).(var)(:,1) end . This is what i tried. is it not possible to use this way? I just wanna append it as one read out the values from that. could you please tell a better to work around. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @VijayKG: See edited answer. It is best to not generate variable names in a program, but to use MATLAB's data structures instead. If you *really*, *really* want to do it your way, you need to use `eval`. It will be slow, difficult to read, difficult to maintain. I highly recommend you follow the suggestion I gave above.

Comment: Thanks alot for the support Cris. It is perfect. As you suggested, better to use cells and read the data from it.